# Hausdorff measure of unit interval under snowflaking

Tags: metric-spaces, fractals, hausdorff-measure

What general properties are known of the function defined as follows: Let $H:[1,\infty[\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $H(t):=\mathcal{H}^t([0,1],\|\cdot\|^\frac{1}{t})$?

Given the difficulty of computing the Hausdorff measure of the Koch snowflake I don't expect explicit values, just general non trivial results.

Comment: Is the second argument of $\cal H^t$ meant to define a norm?

Comment: @markmcclure yes, i mean the snowflaked version of the euclidean norm

Comment: can you compute some value of $H$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any metric space $(X,d)$, any $s>0$ and any $t\ge 1$ we have 
$$
\mathcal H^{ts}(X, d^{1/t}) = \mathcal H^s(X, d)
$$

Indeed, let $(E_k)$ be a cover of $X$ by sets of small diameter that almost achieves $\mathcal H^s(X, d)$, that is 
$$
\sum_k (\operatorname{diam}E_k)^s \le \mathcal H^s(X, d) + \epsilon
$$

In the snowflaked version of $X$ (distinguished by subscript $t$), $\operatorname{diam}_tE_k = (\operatorname{diam} E_k)^{1/t}$. Hence 
$$
\sum_k (\operatorname{diam}_tE_k)^{ts} = \sum_k (\operatorname{diam}E_k)^s
$$
which proves $\mathcal H^{ts}(X, d^{1/t}) \le \mathcal H^s(X, d)$. The reverse inequality follows in the same fashion.

#### Summary

Abstract "snowflaking", by raising the metric to a power, is easy.  The difficulty with von Koch curve is that it's not exactly the same as raising the metric on an interval to a power (it's only bi-Lipschitz equivalent). Concrete realizations of snowflakes are more difficult to handle than abstract ones: there are all these bends in various directions, and it's not obvious what the optimal covers should look like.

Comment: Oh I see. I made the mistake in assuming that the Hausdorff measure is invariant under biLipschitz maps, but this is only true for the dimension. Thanks.